# Man pages: When to put a new system call in section 2 and when in section 3?

Tags: man, minix, syscalls

For an exercise at the university, we are asked to extend Minix (v2) with a system call `utctime` that properly calculates the leap seconds (which Minix' implementation of `time` does not do).

We've created a new system call, and created a new library function that wraps this system call that was added to `<time.h>`.

Now, we'd like to add a man-page for `utctime`. However, `time` has both a man-page in section 2 (system calls) as well as section 3 (library calls).

Should we add the `utctime` to both of these? Or only to `2` because it is not a standardized C library call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest section 2.  Consider, for instance, the `open` system call — actually, the C library function wrapper over the `open` system call — which is documented only in section 2.

Answer (score 1):

If the function lives in the kernel itself, not a userspace C library, then put it in section 2.

Section 3 is not only for libc functions, they can be other libraries which provide low-level operating system subroutines that are not part of the kernel.  For example PAM function manual pages are stored in section 3.

In this case if you have a kernel system call and a library function, put the man page for the system call in section 2 and the man page for the library function in section 3.

Comment: So in this case the library function `time_t utctime(time_t *)` was added to `/usr/includes/time.h`, with its source defined in `/usr/src/lib/libc/sys-minix/utctime.c`. And it is a direct wrapper of the system call, only performing `_SYSCALL(PM_PROC_NR, UTCTUME, &m);` and returning the proper field of the message-object from the function (as well as, akin to `time`, setting the pointer passed as argument if not NULL to the same value).

Would this be 'enough of a library function' to create a section-3 man page for besides the section-2 page or not?

Comment: Yes, if `utctime` is a modification to libc and lives in userspace (not compiled into the kernel) then it is a library function, even if it is a trivial wrapper of a kernel function. In most systems, library code when executed runs in an entirely different memory region with different privileges from the kernel code. Consider `execv` and `execve`. `execve` is a kernel function and in section 2.  `execv` is a function in [libc](https://code.woboq.org/userspace/glibc/posix/execv.c.html) that just calls `execve` without a customizable env parameter, and its man page is in section 3.